# Angular 2 - Routing useAsDefault not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, routes, angular

I am using angular 2 for routing and node for hosting locally.

When I use 'useAsDefault:true' for my route the nav bar links no longer work and the URL goes to http://localhost/ (Blank Page) when I want it to go to http://localhost/home

One I remove the flag the nav bar works correctly and I am able to go to the /home route but I go to the blank page

Can anyone shed any light on why the default flag is not working correctly ?

**App.Component.ts**

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent /*, useAsDefault : true */},
  { path: '/articles', name: 'Posts', component: PostsComponent  },
  { path: '/detail/:id', name: 'PostDetail', component: PostDetailComponent },
  { path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent  },
])
```

**App.Component.html**

```
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a [routerLink]="['Home']">Home</a></li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="['Posts']">Articles</a></li>
  <li><a href="#p">Publisher</a></li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="['Login']">Login</a></li>
</ul>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Main.ts**

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

bootstrap(AppComponent,  [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <title>Blog</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">

     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <blog-app>Blog Loading...</blog-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add a route for every route one is trying to access that is not defined and redirect it to your home route:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '/articles', name: 'Posts', component: PostsComponent },
  { path: '/detail/:id', name: 'PostDetail', component: PostDetailComponent },
  { path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '/**', redirectTo: ['Home'] }
])
```

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work. Same behaviour as useAsDefault. (Nav bar not working and no redirect)

Comment: Thank you!  That last line you show `{ path: '/**', redirectTo: ['Home'] }` is was i was browsing many SO articles looking for since I couldn't find this in the angular.io docs.

Comment: Glad it helped you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Might b late:

`useAsDefault` is deprecated, use this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'heroes',        component: HeroListComponent },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

official doc: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Answer (score 0):

When you use the useasdefault it means that you've a parent route and within it there's child routes ie

```
localhost:8000/dashboard/dashboard
localhost:8000/dashboard/settings
```

the two url routes will be set under a parent url like this:

```
{path: '/dashboard/...', component:Dashboard}
```

then in the Dashboard component you now create the dashboard root and the settings route as child routes like this:

```
{path: 'dashboard', component:DashboardAdmin, useAsDefault: True}
{path: 'settings', component:Settings}
```

in your case, figure out what you need encapsulated. for instance, `home, article` and `detail` could be under one parent url say:

```
{path: '/home/...' component: HomeDataComponent}
{ path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent  },
```

then move the three urls config into `HomeDataComponent` or whichever name you give it:

```
@RouteConfig([
{ path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent , useAsDefault : true},
{ path: '/articles', name: 'Posts', component: PostsComponent  },
{ path: '/detail/:id', name: 'PostDetail', component: PostDetailComponent },
])
```

When using `useAsDefault` you need to have the parent route and the `useAsDefault` on the child route you want to appear first.

Check [this](https://auth0.com/blog/2016/01/25/angular-2-series-part-4-component-router-in-depth/) for a detailed explanation. Hope it works.